# Непонятное поведение объекта в Powershell

Tags: powershell

Есть объект Departmaent, один из атрибутов которого это GUID.

Вот так не работает, ругается что объект не содержит атрибута GUID

```
$OUObject = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {description -eq $Department.GUID} -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase $BasePath
```

А если присвоить значение другой переменной и в фильтре использовать её, ошибок нет.

```
$GUID = $Department.GUID
$OUObject = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {description -eq $GUID} -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase $BasePath
```

Не пойму почему такое поведение, приведение значение атрибута объекта к ToString(), тоже не даёт эффекта.

В чем суть такого поведения?

Comment: Напишите текст ошибки

Comment: Ответ был прост, так ведет себя Powershell, подробнее http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306898/get-aduser-filter-fails-when-comparing-to-an-objects-property